# Calculate Max Number Of Harmonics for given Sample Rate?

Tags: sampling, nyquist

How do I calculate the maximum number of harmonics a complex wave can have based on the sample rate?

Say I Have a 20hz fundamental and a sampling rate of 44100 hz. My instinct is to take 44100/2 = 22050(nyquist) and the take the fundamental and multiply by 2 while the frequency is less than nyquist and the count how many times I had to multiply.

I would like to know if i'm going in the right direction and if i'm not... what is the correct way to do this?

EDIT:
I would like to add that I am creating a table based oscillator with multiple tables with different harmonic contents.I am trying to figure out how to calculate the harmonics each table should have if I have an arbitrary number of tables. So **table 1** would have say **500 harms** so a **max freq of 44.1hz** and **table n** would have **x harms** and have a **max freq of y**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't just multiply by 2, you multiply by every integer.  You can have a 2nd harmonic, a 3rd harmonic, 4th, etc.  (Only multiplying by 2s would tell you the number of octaves, not the number of harmonics.)

So take Nyquist frequency, and divide by the fundamental frequency

> 22050 Hz / 20 Hz = 1102.5

Then round down to the nearest integer.  So you can fit 1102 harmonics.  The 1102th harmonic is 1102*20 = 22040 Hz, while the 1103th harmonic is 1103*20 = 22060 Hz, which is too high.

(Note that some [consider the fundamental as the 0th harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency) while others consider it the first harmonic.  I am counting it as the first, 1*f.)

Comment: please see my edit for the question. I added a bit to clarify why i needed this info. thanks for your help